# how to remove white strip from scrollable tab?

Tags: android

i have made a tab scrollable, problem is it shows a white strip to indicate more tab are available , how to get rid of this strip from beginning & end?
[image: tab with white strip at end]

here is xml:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/menu_bg" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Scrollable tabs are already available through ActionBar (you have a compatibility lib in sdk samples). White strip will always be visible since this is a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `android:fadingEdge="none"` in your xml, or [`setFadingEdgeLength`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setFadingEdgeLength%28int%29) in code.